# Add unique constraint to an existing PostgreSQL index

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing, unique-constraint

I have an index in my PostgreSQL 9.3 database:

```
CREATE INDEX index_foos_on_bar_and_baz ON foos USING btree (bar, baz);
```

(from a schema migration using Ruby on Rails)

The index is present and made things faster. Now that I've cleaned up duplicate foos, I'd like to make this index unique:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_foos_on_bar_and_baz ON foos USING btree (bar, baz);
```

Is there a way to alter the existing index and make it unique? Or is it easier/faster to delete the existing index and create a new, unique one?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no way to change an index to unique index. You can see what you can change to index at [alter index document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-alterindex.html).

In this case you need to drop and create new unique index.

Answer (score -3):

You can alter an index to add the "UNIQUE" constraint with:

```
 ALTER TABLE distributors 
 ADD CONSTRAINT dist_id_zipcode_key
 UNIQUE (dist_id, zipcode);
```

See the official documentation here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html

Comment: How does this alter the existing index? It seems to just create a new unique constraint.

Comment: This looks like it creates both the INDEX and UNIQUE constraint on it, pretty cool. Is this expected behavior? Also , the UNIQUE constraint must be dropped  to remove the INDEX - you cannot directly remove the INDEX as postgres throws an error because the CONSTRAINT is dependent on the INDEX

Comment: When a unique constraint or primary key is defined for a table, PostgreSQL automatically creates a unique index, but your answer is incorrect for this question because it creates a new unique index, and the table now has two indexes, the first of which is no longer required.